# Type for referencing keys of another property on the same object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an object composed of Records mapping string keys to known types.

```
type Material = string;
type Mesh = { material: string };
interface Library {
  materials: Record<string, Material>;
  meshes: Record<string, Mesh>;
}
```

Some of those known types may need to reference a value from another record: for example a `Mesh` has a `material` and the value for that property must be a key of the `materials` record.

This is how I turned that constraint into types:

```
type Material = string;
type Mesh<MaterialId> = {
  material: MaterialId;
}

interface Library<
  MaterialId extends string
> {
  materials: Record<MaterialId, Material>;
  meshes: Record<string, Mesh<MaterialId>>;
}
```

That works, and trying to set a `material` to a string that doesn't exist on the `materials` record  will cause an error:

```
function loadLibrary<T extends string>(lib: Library<T>) {}

// Not valid
loadLibrary({
  materials: {
    plastic: "./plastic.png",
    metal: "./metal.png"
  },
  meshes: {
    ball: { material: "plastic" },
    pipe: { material: "metal" },
    chair: { material: "wood" }
  }
});
```

However, the error I get here is that the property `"wood"` is missing on the `materials` record. The error I want is that `"wood"` is not a valid value for `material` because it doesn't exist on the record.
The reason I want this is that if I try to reference a value that doesn't exist, I want that reference to be marked as an error so I know to either add that type to the relevant record or use an existing one. It's not useful to have `material` accept any string and trigger an error on the record, instead of the other way around.

```
loadLibrary({
  materials: { // << There's nothing wrong here, `materials` should be what defines the valid values for this type.
    plastic: "./plastic.png",
    metal: "./metal.png"
  },
  meshes: {
    ball: { material: "plastic" },
    pipe: { material: "metal" },
    chair: { material: "wood" } // << The error should be "wood", it's not a key of `materials`.
  }
});
```

Is this possible? Or can I not control which of the references to that generic type control the valid values for it?

Here's a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghsCAnAlnANlAvFAzsVAOwHMBuAKFElglwAsAeeRVDASQBMA+bKAb3JQoAWwTI06AFywxrdJwoBfcuRSEWAMzgBjaABkUAIyRwkIBoJksJnKBAAeiQh1x4Ca4uR4Cho6xlxpACUIbQB7JA4mWRsOABorcQwuCl9aOlpg0Iio-CJiBJh06P95bhTyZXINAFdCbWAUMMIodDC4DgNjU3MAFTtHCGdXPI8uAAp0I2kukzMGXq4ASn4qto7ZnvGfERiA6T4oAHojqAYGKF6MpAgAcldCMOA6DygAdyRm4ihriASAAz8SXQuH+eDoYRq6A4UEM0DedAQUA4EA0aloUGe0AAbhgUDDcegahiNBFMS9XFQIAA6SxCMDoOD4FDaaQAImpRwZTMa2mpYBIbLidJEEGAGHZnOEYow-MFlkUwrS9Ey-BFhgwUn4u1K7O5zO0bKgipFYBQkAOOuB7Ol4vQRpNQiE2kRKCQlqBcnZbzCYQ4DuOp3OlwydiQnyQ4Mh0Nh0DZPr9QqgKGA9ygj2AUDgUAA1hAQFAwhooIC9iD-rShMpFEsKEA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slightly change your generic constraint to achieve this:

```js
interface Library<
  Materials extends Record<string, Material>
> {
  materials: Materials;
  meshes: Record<string, Mesh<keyof Materials>>;
}

function loadLibrary<T extends Record<string, Material>>(lib: Library<T>) {}

loadLibrary({
  materials: {
    plastic: "./plastic.png",
    metal: "./metal.png"
  },
  meshes: {
    ball: { material: "plastic" },
    pipe: { material: "metal" },
    chair: { material: "wood" }, // Type '"wood"' is not assignable to type '"plastic" | "metal"'.(2322)
  }
});
```

This works because we're now using the generic to define `materials` **only** and deriving `meshes` from it, whereas before TypeScript would try to make both `materials` and `meshes` satisfy `MaterialId extends string` by making it a union of the values of `materials` and the keys of `meshes`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thank you!